# How to format attributes while exporting it to CSV in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm trying to export some records to CSV, so in my controller I have the following:

```
...
send_data @orders.to_csv, filename: "orders-#{Date.today}.csv"
...
```

And in model I have the following:

```
     def self.to_csv

        attributes = %w{ customer_name created_at order_id currency discount subtotal_tax total }

        CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
          csv << attributes
          all.each do |order|
            if order['created_at']
              order['created_at'] = order['created_at'].strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
            end
            csv << attributes.map{ |attr| order.send(attr) }
          end
        end

      end
```

I'd like to format some of the parameter as you can see from this code:

```
if order['created_at']
  order['created_at'] = order['created_at'].strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
end
```

So I'd have the time formatted how I want, however this is not working.

Any ideas why?

EDIT: My Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
    ruby '2.2.2'

    gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
    gem 'sprockets', '3.1.0'
    gem 'devise'
    gem 'angular-rails-templates'
    gem 'mongoid', '~>4'
    gem 'bson_ext'
    gem "mongoid-enum"
    gem "haml-rails"
    gem 'simple_form'
    gem 'bootstrap_form'
    gem 'mongoid-slug'
    gem 'carrierwave-mongoid', :require => 'carrierwave/mongoid'
    gem 'mini_magick'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    gem 'turbolinks'
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
    gem 'rest-client'
    gem 'execjs'
    gem 'therubyracer'
    gem 'redis-rails'
    gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'
    gem 'mongoid-versioning'
    gem 'rack-cors'
    gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
    gem 'sidekiq', '~> 3.4.2'
    gem 'sidetiq'
    gem 'sinatra', '>= 1.3.0', :require => nil
    gem 'puma'
    gem 'paypal-sdk-rest'
    gem "mongoid-paperclip", :require => "mongoid_paperclip"
    gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.3.4'
    gem 'money-rails'
    gem 'geocoder'
    gem 'kaminari'
    gem 'mongoid_auto_increment'
    gem 'aws-sdk-rails'
    gem 'mailcatcher'

    group :development, :test do
        gem "faker", "~> 1.4.3"
        gem 'guard-rails'
        gem 'spork-rails'
        gem 'guard-spork'
        gem 'childprocess'
        gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
        gem 'rspec-rails'
        gem 'guard-rspec'
        gem 'rb-fsevent', :require => false
        gem 'guard-livereload', require: false
        gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
        gem 'database_cleaner'
        gem 'byebug'
        gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
        gem 'spring'
        gem 'mongoid-rspec'
        gem 'capybara'
        gem 'factory_girl_rails'
        gem 'capistrano',         require: false
        gem 'capistrano-rvm',     require: false
        gem 'capistrano-rails',   require: false
        gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
        gem 'capistrano3-puma',   require: false
        gem 'capistrano-secrets-yml', '~> 1.0.0'
    end

    group :doc do
        gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0'
    end

    group :production do
        gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so elegant solution, but it works:

Go to `app/config/initializers` and create file `date_format.rb`. Fill it with :

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d/%m/%Y"
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d/%m/%Y"
```

Your model should look like this now:

```
  def self.to_csv

    attributes = %w{ customer_name created_at order_id currency discount subtotal_tax total }

    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
         csv << attributes

         datetime = DateTime.now

         all.each do |order|
           if order['created_at']
             order['created_at'] =  datetime.to_formatted_s(:default)
           end
           csv << attributes.map{ |attr| order.send(attr) }
         end
       end
  end
```

In case that you want to add time, just update `date_format.rb` to :

```
 Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"
 Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"
```

It was very challenging. I Hope it helps.

[reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-to_formatted_s)

**EDIT**

---

There is one more solution for your model. Please let me know if that works for you. Just replace the code below with the previous one. I'm very curious:

```
def self.to_csv

    attributes = %w{ customer_name created_at order_id currency discount subtotal_tax total }

    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes
      all.each do |order|
        if order['created_at']
          order['created_at'] = order.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        end
        csv << attributes.map{ |attr| order.send(attr) }
      end
    end

  end
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work I'm afraid... it didn't change the result at all

Comment: Very strange. I tested it yesterday. Try and put this requirements in your `application.rb` and please let me know if that works out:

`require "date"`
`require "csv"`

I would appreciate If you could send me your Gemfile

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work either. My Gemfile is in my edit.

Comment: I tested it on: `ruby '2.3.0'` and  `gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'`. I will try to test it again based on your Gemfile.

Comment: Thanks mate. Really appreciate your help

Comment: You are welcome! I had problem dependencies installing `ruby -v 2.2.2` , so I switched to `ruby -v 2.2.5` . Basically, `Ruby 2.2.3`  (and earlier including yours) have serious security vulnerabilities. (see ruby-lang.org and search the archives).  I tested it,  and It worked on `ruby 2.2.5` & `rails 4.2.1` take a look at the output of my csv file:

http://imgur.com/a/vy2Dt

I forgot to mention to restart the server after making `date_format.rb` file and updating your code from my answer. It will take effect after restarting your server.

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK Have you found solution for your problem? I don't give up just like that :-) Please try the the new code, below EDIT line, in my answer. I've just uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Tested on a current project.

The first one won't work without updating the model instance (db data), the second loop is just mapped data. Easier to manipulate.

```
  def self.to_csv
    attributes = %w{ customer_name created_at order_id currency discount subtotal_tax total }
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes
      all.each do |order|
        csv << attributes.map do |attr| 
          if attr == 'created_at'
            order.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
          else
            order.send(attr)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```